# Asynchronous Programming

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, librarylink, asynchronous-processing

Consider that you would like to listen for Raw WiFi Packets coming into your NIC. Since Mathematica doesn't have built-in functions for such low level programming (as far as I know), one alternative would be following the steps:

1. launch an executable file through Mathematica: `Run["ReceivePacket.exe > packet.tmp"]`
2. read output file "packet.tmp"
3. do simple data analysis
4. iterate loop (go back to step 1)

The principle of the executable file "ReceivePacket.exe" is simple. It waits for a single Raw WiFi Packet to arrive. When the packet arrives, the data is written to a dump file and the executable ends. Fortunately, the hard work has already been done by [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/), so all that is necessary is to compile the tutorial [saving packets to a dump file](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut7.html) (with minor modifications).

However, there is a significant drawback in this process. By the time Mathematica read the output file "packet.tmp" and re-launch "ReceivePacket.exe", several packets would be 'lost'. Anticipating possible comments: This happens not because the data analysis is time consuming (on the contrary, the data analysis is very simple) neither because window pop-up is slow (the process is in batch mode with no print to screen).

**1st Issue**
Is it possible to improve this process in order to decrease the amount of packet loss?

**2nd Issue**
Is it possible to use MathLink to improve this process?

Comment: Well, you have several choices: `JLink`, `MathLink`, `LibraryLink` are three big players you should take into consideration if you know any Java or C. You wouldn't loose any packages as you can easily buffer them and send them on request to Mathematica. Or you make a package listener that once run, logs all packages to Mathematica. Shouldn't be too hard. If you know Java, go for a small `JLink` program. That is probably less error prone. If you are really talented in C, then of course use C.

Comment: @halirutan _You wouldn't loose any packages_ Small question: by packages you mean packets (from network) or Mathematica packages (user codes)?

Comment: Sorry, yes *network packet*. In German the word has kind of the same meaning :-)

Comment: @halirutan _yes network packet_ No problem, it is really a bit confusing.

Comment: @halirutan _If you are really talented in C_ All libraries are already developed in C, so I guess C would be the initial choice.

Comment: Would you mind to join me in [chat] then we can quickly discuss and clear questions you have.

Comment: @halirutan I'm not that familiar with `MathLink` neither `LibrayLink`. What would you consider be the milestones (command lines, functions, ...) in order to make this new code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34000/discussion-between-halirutan-and-mark-messa).

Comment: @halirutan _Would you mind to join me_ yes, sure. Let's go!

Comment: @halirutan I've just sent you an issue I'm struggling with regarding compilers recognizable by Mathematica. The details are in the chat. Let me know your opinion.

Comment: I wonder if you wouldn't mind renaming this question? From my point of view, it isn't much about "low-level network programming" (you are not capturing the packets in *Mathematica*, after all) but rather running an asynchronous external process. Hence, I feel that the title is misleading as to your real intent: the network aspect of it seems to be at most a motivating example.

Comment: @OleksandrR. _I wonder if you wouldn't mind renaming this question?_ Ok, no problem.

Comment: @OleksandrR. _the title is misleading as to your real intent_ Just to avoid misinterpretations: Before asking the question I didn't know that the solution would be via `LibraryLink` or `AsynchronousTasks`. I didn't even know that _Mathematica_ supported asynchronous features. Therefore, I'm not trying to deceive anyone.

Comment: I didn't intend to imply any duplicity on your part. However, from the first posting of this question (and especially now that it has an accepted answer), I felt it was mistitled. Thanks for renaming it; the new title is much better.

Comment: @Szabolcs Mind to explain what you are expecting from this recent bounty? halirutan has already answered it **flawlessly** (take also a look at the [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34000/discussion-between-halirutan-and-mark-messa)).

Comment: @MarkMessa Check the bounty description. *"One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."*

Comment: @Szabolcs Didn't know this was possible. Basically you're transferring additional points to the accepted answer. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, I should have done that several years ago ....

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let me give you a very basic example, how you can employ an asynchronously running *LibraryLink* function for this specific task. I will not do any real packet listen, but only explain the general setup.

Usually, a [`LibraryFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunction.html) in *Mathematica* is written in C and wrapped with a very small boiler plate code that is needed to attach the function directly to the *Mathematica* Kernel. Once this library is compiled, it can be loaded by [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) which gives you a *Mathematica* function that can be called like a normal *Mathematica* function. Exactly like other functions, the library function blocks the Kernel until it is finished.

This would be a problem, because what you want is a packet listener that runs in the background, catching all network packets while you can analyse them one after another. Therefore, your library packet listener must not block your Kernel. For this purpose, *Mathematica* provides you with a heavily **undocumented** API for asynchronous tasks. What I tell you here can only be found out by trying and reading example code.

You need to study the C file very carefully

```
FileNames["async-tasks-repeating.c", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]
```

and I will use the function `IntBackgroundTask` as an example here. That means, that our *network packets* are simple integers. Let me stop here and just present you a running example. After this, I will try to answer questions you might ask yourself. A very uncommon form of an answer, but lets give it a try:

```
libFile = First@FileNames["async-tasks-repeating.c", {$InstallationDirectory},
     Infinity];
libMain = FileNameJoin[{DirectoryName[libFile], "async-examples-libmain.c"}];

<< CCompilerDriver`
lib = CreateLibrary[{libFile, libMain}, "asyncLib", 
  "IncludeDirectories" -> {DirectoryName[libMain]}];
packetListener = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, 
  "start_int_repeating_background_task", {Integer, Integer}, Integer];

pauseInMilliseconds = 500;
packetCounterInit = 0;

taskID = Internal`CreateAsynchronousTask[packetListener, 
  {pauseInMilliseconds, packetCounterInit}, (packet = {##}) &]

Dynamic[packet]
```

Let's explain what we did:

**What is this `libMain` file?** It is common code that is used in many examples. Therefore, they put it into a separate file once and you have to compile it as well. Btw, giving `"IncludeDirectories"` in the `CreateLibrary` call is important so that `"async-examples.h"` can be found.

- Attention: In version 9.0 the file `"async-examples.h"` seems to be missing completely. Therefore, please create a file `"async-examples.h"` in the same directory where `libMain` is located and copy the [following content](http://hastebin.com/idilinuzuf.vala) into it.

**How do I know the argument types inside `LibraryFunctionLoad`?** (1) Look into the C code of `"start_int_repeating_background_task"`. You see that `Args[0]` and `Args[1]` (line 43-44) are accessed and both with `getInteger`. In the end, you see that the result is set as `Integer` as well (line 46). (2) You study carefully the `Examples.m` file in the following directory

```
FileNames["LibraryLink", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]
```

This will help to clear a lot other questions too!

**How does this `CreateAsynchronousTask` work?** The basic approach is the following: Your library function sets up the background task by initializing the arguments for it. Then you need to call `createAsynchronousTaskWithThread` (line 45) which returns an unique `taskID` that you return as result. **You don't** just call this library function! You need to register it by calling `` Internal`CreateAsynchronousTask `` which will directly start the background task for you. The last argument there is an *event function* that is called, every time your C loop calls `raiseAsyncEvent` (line 29).

**But I have network packets and not only integers. What should I do?** If you look in the C code, you see that a `DataStore` is used (line 21,27,28) to store the result in each iteration of the loop. Please look into the file

```
FileNames["WolframLibrary.h", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]
```

starting in line 133 you find all available functions for asynchronous tasks and `DataStore`. Instead of adding only an integer to your data store, you can add all basic types and even give them names for easier access. Therefore, let's say you do something like this with your data store

```
ioLibrary->DataStore_addNamedInteger(ds, "Data", eventdata);
ioLibrary->DataStore_addNamedString(ds, "Name", "Packets");
```

then the data you receive in *Mathematica* will look like this

```
{"Data" -> 8, "Name" -> "Packets"}
```

This is a very convenient way to send important information of your network packet back.

**The last argument of `` Internal`CreateAsynchronousTask `` is confusing. Where do I put my packet analyzing code?** The last argument of `CreateAsynchronousTask` is the *call-back function* that is called when a new result is pushed by `raiseAsyncEvent` in your asynch. task. This callback function gets 3 arguments and the correspond directly to the 3 arguments you have given `raiseAsyncEvent`. Let us look at its declaration in `WolframLibrary.h`

```
void raiseAsyncEvent(mint asyncTaskID, char* eventType, DataStore data)
```

Therefore, your call-back function should get 3 arguments:

- First, the `AsynchronousTaskObject` itself that can be used to stop the running background task (or start it again).
- The second argument is a string that you could use to e.g. indicate whether a bad packet arrived. The `eventType` can therefore be used to handle different situations in your call-back function.
- The third argument is always a `DataStore` that contains data that can be used in *Mathematica*.

Therefore, instead of using `(packet = {##}) &` like I did which simply sets the variable `packet` for dynamic displaying, you could define a real function:

```
    analyzePacket[task_, "Offline", _] := StopAsynchronousTask[task];
    analyzePacket[_, "Packet", data_] := DoSomethingWithData[data];
    analyzePacket[_, "BadPacket", _] := DoNothing[];
```

In your C code packet sniffing loop, you make a discrimination when e.g. your WIFI is offline. Then you send something like `raiseAsyncEvent(asyncObjID, "Offline, NULL)`, or when a normal packet arrived, you use `raiseAsyncEvent(asyncObjID, "Packet", packetData)`, etc.

**What else can I do with the `AsynchronousTaskObject` that you saved in the variable `taskID`?** Well, we have 4 highlevel *Mathematica* function that you need to really control starting and stopping of asynchronous tasks:

- [`StopAsynchronousTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StopAsynchronousTask.html) - stop asynchronous evaluations from an asynchronous task
- [`StartAsynchronousTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartAsynchronousTask.html) - resume asynchronous evaluations from an asynchronous task
- [`WaitAsynchronousTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitAsynchronousTask.html) - wait for an asynchronous task to complete
- [`RemoveAsynchronousTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveAsynchronousTask.html) - shut down an asynchronous task

Additionally, you should look at

```
Options[Internal`CreateAsynchronousTask]
(* {"PostRemoveAsynchronousTask" -> None, 
 "PostStartAsynchronousTask" -> None, 
 "PostStopAsynchronousTask" -> None, 
 "PreRemoveAsynchronousTask" -> None, 
 "PreStartAsynchronousTask" -> None, 
 "PreStopAsynchronousTask" -> None, "Repeating" -> False, 
 "TaskDetail" -> "", "UserData" -> None, "Visible" -> True} *)
```

Comment: If I have missed to discuss some important point, please comment and I try to elaborate on it.

Comment: 1st problem: `CreateLibrary[{libFile, libMain}, "asyncLib", "IncludeDirectories" -> {DirectoryName[libMain]}]` When I try to create the library, I get the following error message: _CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Links\LibraryLink\LibraryResources\Source\async-tasks-repeating.c(5) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'async-examples.h': No such file or directory >>_. I've searched my entire hard drive for the header file 'async-examples.h' but it is not there.

Comment: The header is within the same directory as the demo files and the `"async-examples-libmain.c"` file. I easily find it with `FileNames["async-examples.h", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]` too.

Comment: The "following content" link appears to be empty.  Reupload?